# Nice Core-Plot implementations OSX

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using Core Plot for a little App I am programming at the moment and I was wondering if there are any good looking examples or resources. With good looking I don't mean the google docs Example App ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Plot includes a number of example apps that demonstrate various features. There is also [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot) on the Core Plot site with links to many apps that use it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that what are you looking for as you have not cleared your question. But i am telling you this link:  http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/  which certainly will help you.